# Grep the line number for multiple occurences of the same string

Tags: grep

I have a file containing data like this:

```
Index: ....
bla
bla
bla
Index: ....
bla
bla
bla
Index: ....
bla
bla
bla
```

Is there a way I can get the line number for each occurrence of `Index:` and then add this number to an array containing the line number of each occurrence of `Index:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with `grep -n` & `cut`:

```
arr=( $(grep -n Index file | cut -d: -f1) )
```

but even easier with `awk`:

```
arr=( $(awk '/Index/ {print NR}' file) )
```

In both cases the shell array `arr` will hold line numbers the `Index` appears on in `file`.